# Grails Unit test controller

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm trying to do a Unit test on this controller. I'm new to this sort of testing so I dont know from where do I start and how to test things that are needed to be tested, like user, render view.)

```
class ShoppingCartController {

    def shoppingCartWebshopService
    def shoppingCartService
    def springSecurityService
    def checkoutOperaService
    def databaseService
    def dodAdresaService

    def payingOrder(SetShop1Command cmd) {

        def user = springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() ? springSecurityService.currentUser.sifpartnera : null
        def tempAdrese = databaseService.getAdrese(user)
        def adrese = []
        tempAdrese.each{
            adrese.add(it.adresa)
        }

        if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
            render(view: 'OrderChoseAddress', model: [cmd : cmd, params : params, adrese: adrese ])
        }

        def inputUnAdrese = params.inputUnAdrese

        [inputUnAdrese: inputUnAdrese, adrese: adrese]
    }
```

This is my test

```
@Mock([SpringSecurityService,DatabaseService])
@TestFor(ShoppingCartController)
class ShoppingCartControllerTests {

void testPayingOrder(){

    when:
    // params.user = 19
    // user.equals(id)
    // println user
    // controller.OrderChoseAddress()
        controller.params.user = "admin"
        controller.databaseService = new DatabaseService()

    then:
        assert model.adrese != null
}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Could you be more specific about what you're exactly trying to do? And what problems are you facing?

Comment: I would like to do a Unit test of payingOrder in my controller, what is the best way to do something like that? I would like to find out what is input in action and output of it, what am I expecting on the output.